# About spring mvc annotation use properties files

Tags: spring-mvc, properties

You know we can use properties files data in Spring mvc xml file.
for example:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"> 
<property name="location"> 
<value>xxxx.properties</value> 
</property> 
</bean>

...
<mvc:mapping path="/${path}/*" />
...
```

but how I could use it in annotation 
like:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/${url}")
```

now it's wrong.

Tell me how to do
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Spring doesnt resolve `${x}` inside `@RequestMapping`, indeed `{x}` is used for `@PathVariable`. It's not possible to pass non-constant variables to annotations so you can't use `@Value` either.

I believe its not possible to do what you intend through annotations.